# Fetch data from two table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

**How to fetch the data from two table in codeigniter?**

One table in category and other one is products.
I fetch the data from products table but it shows the **category id**, how can I show the **category name** with products data.
same issue in cart table in cart table.

[image]

Comment: Please post code that you have tried? You can write join query for the same

Comment: I just use the simple select statement that's working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch data from product table with category table

```
$this->db->select('p.*,c.cat_name')
     ->from('products p')
     ->join('cat c','p.p_cat = c.cat_name','left');
$products_with_category = $this->db->get()->result();
```

And, to fetch data from cart table with products table and category table info

```
$this->db->select('cart.*,p.p_name,c.cat_name')
     ->from('cart')
     join('products p','p.p_id = cart.cart_p_id','left')
     join('cat c','c.cat_name = p.p_cat','left');
$cart_data = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `cat_id` column in your product table, and use join to fetch data from 2 tables, like this :

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->join('cat', 'products.cat_id = cat.cat_id');
$query = $this->db->get('products');
return $query->result();
```

Comment: I"ll try my best and then tell you either working or not BTW thanks